# How to get auth from a LDAPS server using angular 7 webapp

Tags: angular, active-directory, ldap

I've received the following data

```
server url: vpn.example.com.br:8636
username: example
password: examplepassword
```

How can I use only this data to get LDAPS token or some sort of permission to read the client database, using angular 7?

they use an LDAPS server, I just need to retrieve the user data, I'm used to use HTTP auth, never used LDAPS before.. I dont know how to do the request using angular.. is it a post request to the url?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to give you any useful answer. Is that server actually an LDAPS server? Does their database actually use LDAP authentication? What have you actually tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: Yes, they use an LDAPS server, I just need to retrieve the user data, I'm used to use HTTP auth, never used LDAPS before.. I dont know how to do the request using angular.. is it a post request to the url?